# why is python running here?

Tags: bash, python

Ubuntu 20.04. Using bash. I made a typo. I can simplify to:

```
a </
```

Basically: unknown command with stdin redirected from a directory.

I would expect the result to be:

```
a: command not found
```

However with Ubuntu 20.04 (not debian) and bash (not busybox, dash, ksh, tcsh), I get:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: <stdin> is a directory, cannot continue
Python runtime state: core initialized

Current thread 0x00007f83aacaa740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

What's going on? Why is python involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash implements this functionality via a `command_not_found_handle` function:

```
$ declare -f -p command_not_found_handle
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

As you can see, the function attempts to call `/usr/lib/command-not-found` - which is a python script:

```
$ file /usr/lib/command-not-found
/usr/lib/command-not-found: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

with the function name (in this case `a`) as argument. However the shell has already redirected standard input from `/` - so it's effectively calling `python3` with the input redirection:

```
$ python3 </
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: <stdin> is a directory, cannot continue
Python runtime state: core initialized

Current thread 0x00007f16b0ab0740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

You can see the sequence more clearly if you run your command with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ 
$ a </
+ a
+ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
+ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- a
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: <stdin> is a directory, cannot continue
Python runtime state: core initialized

Current thread 0x00007feb94250740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
+ return 1
```

Comment: I'd just worked out the what but not the why. Thanks for the details.

Comment: @jhnc tbh I was surprised that bash itself doesn't immediately barf on the `</` redirection